# Does this code has actually a quadratic complexity?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, time-complexity

Recently I've seen one solution for the following algorithmic problem:

> Given an array of integers, return a new array where each element in
>   the array is the number of smaller elements to the right of that
>   element in the original input array.
>
> for example, given the array [3, 4, 9, 6, 1], return [1, 1, 2, 1, 0]

And here is the solution in python:

```
import bisect

    def smaller_counts(lst):
        result = []
        seen = []
        for num in reversed(lst) :
            i = bisect.bisect_left(seen, num)
            result.append(i)
            bisect.insort(seen, num)
    return list(reversed(result))
```

**Problems code.**

The authors of this solution claims that it has O(nlogn) complexity, but it seems incorrect to me.

**And here is my calculations for complexity:**

In the code above the function **bisect_right** is simply doing a binary search so the complexity of it is **O(logn)**.
Let's look at the [source codes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/bisect.py) of insort:

```
def insort_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.
    If x is already in a, insert it to the right of the rightmost x.
    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    lo = bisect_right(a, x, lo, hi)
    a.insert(lo, x)

def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.
    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e <= x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e > x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just after the rightmost x already there.
    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo
```

**Code 1.**

Where:

```
bisect = bisect_right
insort = insort_right
```

**Code 2.**

It is obvious that **insort_right** takes **O(n)** time because it performs a binary search at the beginning which takes **O(logn)** time then inserts an element that takes **O(n)** time.

Now let's take a look at the implementation of **insert** function in [python codes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c):

```
static PyObject *
list_insert_impl(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t index, PyObject *object)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=7f35e32f60c8cb78 input=858514cf894c7eab]*/
{
    if (ins1(self, index, object) == 0)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    return NULL;
}

static int
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n = Py_SIZE(self);
    PyObject **items;
    if (v == NULL) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    if (n == PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
            "cannot add more objects to list");
        return -1;
    }

    if (list_resize(self, n+1) < 0)
        return -1;

    if (where < 0) {
        where += n;
        if (where < 0)
            where = 0;
    }
    if (where > n)
        where = n;
    items = self->ob_item;
    for (i = n; --i >= where; )
        items[i+1] = items[i];
    Py_INCREF(v);
    items[where] = v;
    return 0;
}
```

**Code 3**

So we can notice that insert takes O(n) time because of shifting elements in **static int ins1(...)**.
Now let's calculate how is it going in **Problems code**.
At first, it calls **bisect.insort(seen, num)** and the list **seen** contains only one element. In the second iteration **seen** contains two elements.
During n-th iteration the list **seen** already contains n elements so the operations count can be written like this way:
**1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n - 1 + n** which is **n(n + 1)/2** which is **O(n^2)**.
So for some i-th iteration, it takes **O(logn)** time for binary search and **O(n)** time for insertion (in the body of main for loop).
So in the end, the complexity for the whole problem becoms **O(n^2)**.
Are my calculations correct for complexity of this problem?

---

Comment: Most reasonable approaches to this problem would have O(n^2) complexity. After all, you have to (1) check how many elements in the remainder of the list are less than the current one, which is O(n), and (2) do that for every element in the list, which is also O(n). So overall the problem would be O(n^2).

Comment: Your code analysis seems correct. You use n for both the size of the problem and the loop variable in the last couple of sentences, but it is still basically correct: For the i-th iteration it takes O(log i) + O(i / 2) and summing that from i=0 to i=n should give O(n log n) + O(n^2/2) => O(n^2).  I'm assuming some kind of heap data structure could do better, but that's just a hunch...

Comment: thebjorn - Also a self-balancing tree could be used to use this problem in O(nlogn) time. In this approach, we will have some array which will keep the indices of the elements like they are in the original array. Then we will iterate over self-balancing tree finding those elements which indices are greater than the index of the current element.

Comment: Your calculations seem to be correct for this approach. However, I'd recommend you to read "Inversion Count" problem, which has 2 commonly known approach which use "Merge Sort algo" and "Binary Index Tree algo" to solve it in O(n logn)

Comment: vish4071 - Thanks for Binary index Tree it is something new for me to explore. Once I've solved inversion count problem via Merge Sort algorithm, I suppose it can be used to calculate smaller elements in merge stage.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: The naive approaches take O(n^2), but you can do O(nlogn) with an approach based on a modified mergesort, much like what's involved in solutions for [counting inversions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/).

Comment: You could also use a different data structure than a sorted list for `seen`, like a binary search tree. In practice, in Python, you might use a SortedList from the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) project, which has a worse big-O bound, but good practical performance.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: Correct. Also, red-black tree/avl tree could be used + some additional array for keeping indices could be used to solve this problem in O(nlogn) time complexity.